# Display issues after running latest updates for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, updates, radeon

I have Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit on a dual boot with Windows 7 64-bit and installed updates over the past Friday.

Saturday when I booted up, the login screen had major graphical issues where it looks like almost the entire screen is blocked out with a weird striped screen. I can just barely see my wallpaper at the top and I can log in.

I am running a Radeon HD 6570 video card using ATI's drivers. Since Saturday, I have tried to repair from disc but the issue remained. I tried reinstalling fresh and I get the proper image until I run updates. I've basically tried everything I can think of but the issue always comes back after the latest updates.

As of right now I think my options are to go back to 12.04, try 12.10 64-bit, or try one of the generic proprietary drivers.

I know of the issue involving Radeon, ATI and the blank desktop/no mouse situation but this isn't related to that as I can get it to happen without having Catalyst on the system.

Any insight, help, or shared grieving would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue here...and have the same OS config....using ATI Radeon HD 6670..I think its a problem with the Graphic card driver...The FGLRX Propripetory driver installer is not working...so I am trying to download the Linux catalyst driver from here...http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx... Try it out..it might solve the problem...I am still downloading...
       For the time being i just changed my Graphics preference to internal in my BIOS setup...works fine with only internal...you can do the same till we find a solution..

Comment: I know 13.1 will give you the same issues with Unity and mouse missing so I'm concidering trying the 12.11 beta as it was reported to fix the other graphic issue

Comment: @Ralkkai There's no 13.1 or 12.11 version of Ubuntu. Newer-than-stable versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here, as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: I meant for Catalyst. Sorry for not being specific.